# Which nvidia driver deb-package should I install for gtx1050ti?

Tags: apt, nvidia, gpu, proprietary-drivers

I already installed the Nvidia drivers for gtx1050ti once manually, but it made some problems occassionaly, like suddenly the driver being erased out of thin air.

So, I would like to install it this time as a deb package, however there are different packages, when I type

```
apt search nvidia
```

each one for a couple of GPUs, but how do I know in which package to choose, could not find the answer on the nvidia's webpage?

**I am unsing Ubuntu 16.04**

Comment: There is only one version : 375.39 . ... the other one, "367" will also install 375.39 → I.e. it's a "Transitional package for nvidia-375" http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/nvidia-367